# Scala - Build SBT - Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I am getting following error while running my akka project using built using build.sbt.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.airwave.feeder.FeederApp.main(FeederApp.scala)
    Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:152)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:170)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:176)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:184)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:246)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:168)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:530)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:109)
        at com.airwave.feeder.FeederApp$.<init>(FeederApp.scala:55)
        at com.airwave.feeder.FeederApp$.<clinit>(FeederApp.scala)
        ... 1 more

My application.conf looks like following:
cat src/main/resources/application.conf 
akka {
    stdout-loglevel = "OFF"                 // supress console logging
    loglevel = "DEBUG"                      // use INFO as default
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
    lower-bound = 5
    upper-bound = 100
}
```

I am using sbt for building my fat jar. Do I need to modify build.sbt file?

Thanks